# How can i deploy heroku scheduler on python app

Tags: python, heroku, scheduler

I have an app,which finds fake users and sends their id  to the server.At the moment it works like this:
app.py

```
app = Flask(__name__) 


@app.route("/", methods=['GET']) 
def main(): 
    answer1 = np.load('firs_answer.npy', allow_pickle=True).item() 
    answer2 = np.load('second_answer.npy', allow_pickle=True).item() 
    return json.dumps({'answer1 ':answer1 ,'answer2 ':answer2 }) 

#and second func 
def reader(): 
    while (True): 
        answer1 = find_answer(data1) 
        answer2 = find_answer(data2) 
        np.save('firs_answer.npy') 
        np.save('second_answer.npy') 
        time.sleep(86400) 
p1 = threading.Thread(target=reader) 
p1.start() 

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    app.run()
```

But I want to deploy scheduler 
First I install free sched add-ons in heroku,then a add clock,in clock.py

clock.py

```
import sys

sys.path.append('app')

from app import app
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler

sched = BlockingScheduler()

@sched.scheduled_job('interval', seconds=10)
def scheduled_job():
    app()

sched.start()
```

But it doesn't work

What should I do?